# Displaying records from a database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I just recently learned how to grab the content from a database using mysqli. I'm trying to create a quiz. This is what I got in terms of code:

```
<p class="question"><?php 

            error_reporting(0);
            require 'connect.php';


            if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM questions")){
                    if($count = $result->num_rows){




                        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                            echo $row->question, '<br>';
                        }

                        $result->free();
                    }

            }
            ?></p>
            <ul class="answers">
            <form action="">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">1</label><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">10</label><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">12</label><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">7</label><br/>
                <input type = "submit" value="submit">
            </form>
            </ul>
```

The output of this is,

```
1. The answer to 10+10 is?
//radio buttons here followed by submit.
```

Basically, I am getting the question from the database.

A problem with this is that if I add more questions to the database, they will go directly beneath 1. The answer to 10+10 is?. This is a problem as the output would be:

```
The answer to 10+10 is?
The answer to 5+5 is?
The answer to 15+15 is?
//Radio buttons with answers from question 1
//Radio buttons with answers from question 2
//Radio buttons with answers from question 3
```

How can I modify the code so the possible answers goes below that respective answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add the possible answers as well in the table as the possible answers will also vary based on the question. eg (10 + 10) None of our answers is the correct answer as you mentioned in html. Then using loop display the questions along with possible answers

```
Q_ID |    question    | ans1 | ans2 | ans3 | ans4 |  answer
 1     '10 + 10 is ?'    30     10     40     20       20
 2     ' 5 + 5 is ?'     5      10     20     55       10
```

For that the table creation would be something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `Q_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` char(150) NOT NULL,
  `ans1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ans2` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ans3` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ans4` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Q_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

After this you need to add questions to database through multiple INSERT

Then loop through the result set fetched from the database

```
for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++)
{
$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `Q_id`='$i'");
$quiz = mysql_fetch_assoc($question);

echo $quiz['question'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $Q_id .'" value="' . $quiz['ans1'] . '" />' . $quiz['ans1'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $Q_id .'" value="' . $quiz['ans2'] . '" />' . $quiz['ans2'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $Q_id .'" value="' . $quiz['ans3'] . '" />' . $quiz['ans3'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $Q_id .'" value="' . $quiz['ans4'] . '" />' . $quiz['ans4'] . '<br />';
$Q_id++;
}
```

**Finally this site is not for providing entire code, we can suggest ideas and answer only when the questions are very specific.  For all of your nested questions, do some homework yourself**

- How to get radio button in PHP ?
- How to do multiple inserts ?

Please go through the guidelines on

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hmm, doing it like this would lead to all the records being directly below each other - opposite of my current setup: http://imgur.com/mmr1u7a 

Also, how would I get the radio buttons in your suggestion?

Comment: I've got the database setup as you suggested (http://imgur.com/jTveQfh). I'm a bit unsure as to what I do with my PHP / HTML code now. Also what do you mean by *multiple* insert?